# NullPointerException in Processing, can't find the error

Tags: nullpointerexception, processing

So I am making a simple little program and the IDE is throwing out NullPointerException (http://puu.sh/5TJLZ.png) at this line: `total[0] = calc(coins[0],coins[1],coins[2]);`
Note that `void setupCoins()` and `String calc()` are in separate tabs and not part of the tab.

```
int[] coins;
String[] total;

void setup(){
  size(100,100);
  setupCoins();
  total[0] = calc(coins[0],coins[1],coins[2]);
  saveStrings("data/balance.txt",total);
}

void setupCoins(){

  String[] imports = loadStrings("balance.txt");
  String[] numbers = split(imports[0],',');
  coins = int(numbers);
}

String calc(int gold, int silver, int copper){

  for(int i = 0; i <= copper; i++){
    if(copper>9){
      copper=copper-10;
      silver++;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i <= silver; i++){
    if(silver>9){
      silver=silver-10;
      gold++;
    }
  }

  fill(#F5EE0A);
  ellipse(20,20,10,10);

  fill(#AFAFAF);
  ellipse(20,45,10,10);

  fill(#AA5C46);
  ellipse(20,70,10,10);

  fill(#000000);
  text(gold + " Gold",30,25);
  text(silver + " Silvers",30,50);
  text(copper + " Coppers",30,75);

  return gold + "," + silver + "," + copper;

}
```

Comment: Well, which value is `null`?  If I were to guess, `total[0]` isn't valid because I don't see where you initialize `total`.

Comment: Didn't I initialize it in line 2 `String[] total;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a debugger, you can stop on that line and see which object is actually `null`.  If I were to guess, it's probably `total[0]` because I don't see where you initialize that.

You *declare* it here:

```
String[] total;
```

But you never *initialize* it to a value.  That declaration line doesn't tell the compiler, for example, *how many* elements the array should have.  So it doesn't have any.  But then you try to access an element:

```
total[0] = ...
```

`total[0]` is the *first* element in an array that has no elements, therefore it doesn't exist.  Contrast this to where you initialize some other arrays:

```
String[] imports = loadStrings("balance.txt");
String[] numbers = split(imports[0],',');
```

The methods `loadStrings()` and `split()` presumably return valid arrays, so `imports` and `numbers` are assigned the values of valid arrays.  `total` is never assigned such a value.

Comment: Yep thanks I just got in Processing again and forgot that I have to initialize the number of values in the array. Got it working now! Thanks!